# Using regex in my editor to search and replace, how can I remove newlines only from a certain sections

Tags: regex

I have some document text I'm trying to convert to json and I have some description fields that include newlines I want to remove and quotes I need to escape. I'm using the Intellij editor with regex and am not sure how to define the regex that matched just the description field lines not the other fields & remove the newlines within it.

for example a snippet of the kind of character text is in the document.

```
description: "dsfsdf
sdf"title"
sdfsd9so 233 f
f:sd!f
sdfsdf",

other: "data",
field: "data",
date: "data",

description: "here is more descripton with new lines and quotes
sdf "info"
sdfs'df
fsd-f.(riro)
sdfsdf",

other: "data",
field: "data",
date: "data",
```

I tried 
search of:

```
description: "((([^\n]+)\n\s+)+)
```

replace with:

```
description: "$1
```

I would like the result to be

```
description: "dsfsdf sd\"title\" sdfsd9so 233 f f:sd!f sdfsdf",

other: "data",
field: "data",
date: "data",

description: "here is more descripton with new lines and quotes sdf \"info\" sdfs'df fsd-f.(riro) sdfsdf",

other: "data",
field: "data",
date: "data",
```

Comment: Your need is not very clear. And what did you try?

Comment: can you show a result?

Comment: this is 2 problems: 1) removing newlines 2) escaping quotes. You can't do it in one regex.

Comment: So, what about [this](https://regex101.com/r/ax8zn7/2/), when you get description fields, you can replace every `\n` with space